# Fortify Destruction and Magicka Regen enchantment on armor

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I am the only Dovahkiin in Skyrim (at least until Dragonborn DLC) and also a badass level 100 Destruction and Enchantment skill magi.

Recently I've managed to reach level 100 in Smithing skill and created my first light dragon armor. I'm currently wearing [Master Robes of Destruction](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Master_Robes_of_Destruction) (Magicka regen +150%, Destruction spell use 22% less magicka) and this makes any destruction spell costs **NO** magicka at all (of course plus enchantments on ring, amulet, circlet etc).  The problem is I tried to enchant my light dragon armor with `Fortify Health` and also `Fortify Destruction and Magicka Regen` (since I can enchant 2 enchantments in one item) but the result is not as satisfied as I wanted.

At the moment the maximum I can get is about **17%** for fortify destr. and only mere **10%** for fortify magicka (with enchantment potion). So I have 2 questions:

<strike>1.What is the percentage of maximum effect of an enchantment on an armor?</strike> This question is not relevant anymore

1. Does magnitude of enchantment differs depending on the item? (i.e. boots, clothes, heavy/light armor etc)
2. With every enchanting boost available in Skyrim, it is possible for me to make a light dragon armor with `Fortify Destruction and Magicka Regen` with at least 25% magicka reduction and 50% magicka regen?

Note: Legal methods only please. That means no mods, multi-potions boosting cheat (one potion is OK) and console commands.

PS:

- `Fortify Destruction and Magicka Regen` enchantment is considered as **ONE** enchantment.
- If anyone wondering how the hell I can cast destruction spell without using magicka, just buff up your items with `Fortify Destruction` enchantment until the total reduction of Magicka cost for Destruction spells become above 100%.

*Wuld Nah Kest!* (Runs away)

EDIT: Revised my questions and added some details.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm having a little trouble determining exactly what your problem is, but I will hit your list:

1. I believe without exploiting potions and recursion stat boosting, the maximum percentage of magic reduction on a single enchantment is 25%.  This is with 100 Enchant, 5/5 enchant stat, and the various corresponding element/weapon perks.
2. Magnitude is not affected by armor type.
3. You should be able to smith and enchant Dragon Scale Armor with 100% Destruction magicka reduction(free cast).  Additionally, with the extra enchant perk, you could boost other school's cast regen, or eliminate it completely.

Remember you get the maximum enchantment power when using Grand or Black soul gems.

Comment: Is that meaning clothes/robes have the same magnitude as armors? BTW I made some changes in my question. Hope you can take a look at it.

Comment: You can enchant clothes/robes to the same % as armor.  Armor provides more damage protection through a higher armor rating, but this has no bearing on the power of enchantments.

Answer (score 1):

Base value for enchanting destruction is 8 points so u can get 25% reduction with all the perks, but the destruction base value for destruction & mag. regen is 5 points and magicka does not change, so it will always be 10%, that's why u get only 17% reduction. You can get higher % reduction using potions to fortify enchanting but magicka regen will continue to be 10%. The only way to change that is using mods.

Answer (score 0):

Black soul gems are the best to use better even than grand to do what you want. You need to go up the middle of the enchanting tree, have the bottom perk filled, you need any potion and you get 25% reduction to destruction, illusion etc., and if you fortify magic you get about 60-65 magic regen.  That's about the same that is double enchanting, no potions with black soul gems or black star of asura.

PS. You might have to use the potion enchantment thing; where you make a potion of enhance enchant, which you can in alchemy, then wear them. Then make another potion and repeat until it stops going up.

Comment: This was pretty incoherent.  I've tried to tidy it up, but if I messed up, feel free to roll it back.

Comment: Aren't Black and Grand gems, each with a Grand Soul, functionally identical?  You could get a Grand gem with a lesser soul, but I believe as long as both have a Grand soul, they both provide the same energy.

Answer (score 0):

The 'Fortify [school] and magicka regen' is bugged only the Fortify [school] part goes up and its weaker than normal fortify ... Enchant so you can create fortify hp 62 , fortify destruction 17%(or 22% not sure) + fortify magicka regen 10% (this never changes) or simply create armor with 25 % fortify destruction and 62 hp but you have higher armor rating so it's worth it, and if you can hit armor cap just with gloves and boots (576 ap 80% physical reduction) you can wear master robes.