# Enchanting armor with Fortify Magicka Regen and Fortify [School]?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I'm trying to enchant Elven Armor with the same enchantment as say Master Robes of Destruction. It seems to max out at about 10% magicka regen and 5% Destruction reduction. Is this a glitch or just something that Bethesda didn't want us to do?

- I've maxed out the entire Enchanting tree, meaning I've chosen every perk available in the tree.
- Questions I've previously viewed haven't really addressed this problem.

Comment: Are you using a large enough soul gem? To get the full benefit you want a grand soul.

Comment: Same question already asked. <http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/103244/fortify-destruction-and-magicka-regen-enchantment-on-armor>

Answer (score 2):

The effect of `Fortify [School]` is strongly magnified on robes you can find.  The cost of choosing to wear a robe is quite high.  You would give up 40 hidden armor rating and access to many powerful armor perks (these perks can easily triple your armor rating).

If you could just strip that enchantment out of robes and put it on armor with the same magnitude, there wouldn't ever be a choice or advantage to wearing robes.